# Apache problems (ninja-media-script)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I buyed this script: http://codecanyon.net/item/ninja-media-script/6822888

I would like to run this on a Apache Server.

Now i got the Problem that i must convert the htaccess to Apache rewrite. After hours of trying i hope you can help me.

First .htaccess is this in root folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

in root/public i got this htaccess.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

When will I access the **example.com/install**, displays the 404 error.

Can someone help me please? :)

Comment: Check your apache error logs

Comment: Jon Lin, thx... I did it!